# Python: socket._getaddrinfo is very slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, ubuntu-12.04

We're using Mercurial hooks to connect Mercurial commits to issues in our Jira server, so whenever someone makes a commit, there's a connection being made to our Jira server. We use the `jira-python` package for this, which in turn uses `requests`.

This setup worked great until two days ago where every commit started being really slow (~12 seconds). Profiling the process revealed that `socket._getaddrinfo` takes 99.9% percent of this time. The slowness occures for all our developers and started at the same time.

My initial idea was that maybe there are latency or DNS resolution issues, but `ping`ing our server takes less than a second. What could cause this behavior?

Comment: you might want to check the `/etc/resolv.conf` on the machine that is using `jira-python` to connect to your Jira server. Try `dig @first-ip-in-resolv.conf host.name.of.your.jira.server` and see how long it takes.